# Passing model data to a JavaScript function

Tags: laravel

**Goal:** To pass a model data to a javascript function.

**Problem:** I get an error when trying to pass the model to the JS function call.

In web.php

```
Route::get('/', [noteController::class, 'showNotes']);
```

In noteController.php

```
class noteController extends Controller
{
    public function showNotes() {
        $notes = note::all();
        return view('sidebar', ['notes' => $notes, 'count' => count($notes)]);
    }   
}
```

In index.blade.php

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/note.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    showContent("{{$notes}}");
</script>
```

In note.js (this one is inside a script src in index.blade.php)

```
function showContent(notes) {
  console.log(notes);
  var list = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

  var x = list.findIndex( li => li.className == 'active');

  if (x != -1) {
    var title = document.getElementById('title');
    var content = document.getElementById('content');

    console.log(notes);

    title.nodeValue = notes[x].title;
    content.innerHTML = notes[x].content;
  }
}
```

When I ran the laravel project, The page is being displayed but there's an error in the chrome console of the page.

```
[{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Title 1&quot;,&quot;content&quot;:&quot;It&#039;s Loren ipsum Loren ipsum &quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:null,&quot;updated_at&quot;:null},{&quot;id&quot;:2,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Title 2: The Foo bar&quot;,&quot;content&quot;:&quot;It&#039;s Loren ipsum Loren ipsum &quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:null,&quot;updated_at&quot;:null},{&quot;id&quot;:3,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Title 3: The Bar Foo&quot;,&quot;content&quot;:&quot;It&#039;s Loren ipsum Loren ipsum &quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:null,&quot;updated_at&quot;:null}]
note.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: list.findIndex is not a function
    at showContent (note.js:5)
    at (index):121
showContent @ note.js:5
(anonymous) @ (index):121
```

The error picture [err-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OjFQ.png)

I also tried this in index.php.blade

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    showContent("{{$notes->Json()}}");
</script>
```

But I also got an error:

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::Json does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing collection data you must json_encode it - there's a blade directive to help. Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    showContent(@json($notes));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It was effective, I got an array logged into the console. :)